# No rows selected after I create the insert pl/sql procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I try to insert data to table "school",so I create a text file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHOOL_PRO (id IN NUMBER, name IN VARCHAR2, address IN VARCHAR2, num1 IN INT, num2 IN INT, grade IN INT)
IS
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO SCHOOL (ID,NAME,ADDRESS,NUM1,NUM2,GRADE) VALUES (2016001 , 'G' , 'G' , 160 , 0 , 480);
INSERT INTO SCHOOL (ID,NAME,ADDRESS,NUM1,NUM2,GRADE) VALUES (2016010 , 'H' , 'H' , 150 , 0 , 400);
INSERT INTO SCHOOL (ID,NAME,ADDRESS,NUM1,NUM2,GRADE) VALUES (2016011 , 'S' , 'S' , 150 , 0 , 528);
INSERT INTO SCHOOL (ID,NAME,ADDRESS,NUM1,NUM2,GRADE) VALUES (2016101 , 'J' , 'J' , 20 , 0 , 530);
INSERT INTO SCHOOL (ID,NAME,ADDRESS,NUM1,NUM2,GRADE) VALUES (2016110 , 'B' , 'B' , 10 , 0 , 600);
INSERT INTO SCHOOL (ID,NAME,ADDRESS,NUM1,NUM2,GRADE) VALUES (2016111 , 'Q' , 'B' , 10 , 0 , 580);
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

and I execute the text file,it shows `procedure created`,but then I execute `select * from school` and it shows me `no rows selected`.

Where is the problem lies?Please give me a hand.Thanks!

Comment: The procedure is created, but did you also EXECUTE the procedure? `procedure created` means it has been compiled and it is available to be executed; it doesn't mean it has also been executed. For example, in SQL Developer or in SQL*Plus you could run this command: `exec school_pro`.

Comment: @mathguy It works!Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command creates the procedure, but does not execute it, so nothing is inserted into school. What you'll want to do is one of:

1. Change your procedure so that it inserts the values given as parameters, and then call it for each of the lines to be inserted.
2. Drop the parameters to the procedure (not used) and execute the procedure after creating it.
3. Forget about the procedure and just execute the insert commands.

Comment: Thanks very much!But how I change my procedure so that I can insert data without executing the procedure after creating it.

Comment: @dapao - you don't need a procedure at all to INSERT rows in a table. On the other hand, you can't get any kind of use from a procedure if you don't EXECUTE it; if you just CREATE a procedure but you don't EXECUTE it, then it's as if you never created it in the first place. Creating a procedure has no effect on the world, only executing it does.